# Numba JIT giving LoweringError although code works fine otherwise

Tags: python-3.x, math, jit, mandelbrot

I have the following code in python to calculate the Mandelbrot set. It works fine, but when I try to compile it with JIT by adding `@jit` decorator before the function def, it doesn't work any more. Can anybody tell me why? I would appreciate if you don't criticize my Mandelbrot calculation (I am guessing it could be optimized) and just let me know why JIT doesn't work with this function. By the way, the code is indented after the def. It just didn't appear that way when I inserted it here.

```
def mandelbrot(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,width,height,maxiter):
points=[]
x=np.linspace(xmin,xmax,width)
y=np.linspace(ymin,ymax,height)
for ix,re in enumerate(x):
    points.append([])
    for iy,im in enumerate(y):
        cx=re
        cy=im
        zx=0
        zy=0
        for n in range(maxiter):
            if zx*zx+zy*zy>4.0:
                iters=n
                break
            else:
                oldzx=zx
                oldzy=zy
                zy = 2*oldzx*oldzy+cy
                zx = oldzx*oldzx-oldzy*oldzy+cx  
                iters=n
        points[ix].append(int(iters))
return points
```

I get the following error report with the final line being LoweringError

> runfile('D:/python programs/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.py', wdir='D:/python
>   programs/mandelbrot') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('D:/python programs/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.py', wdir='D:/python programs/mandelbrot')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 786, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "D:/python programs/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.py", line 41, in
>   
>       mandelbrot_set=mandelbrot(-2.0,1.0,-1.5,1.5,500,500,50)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py",
>   line 368, in _compile_for_args
>       raise e
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py",
>   line 325, in _compile_for_args
>       return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py",
>   line 653, in compile
>       cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py",
>   line 83, in compile
>       pipeline_class=self.pipeline_class)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   873, in compile_extra
>       return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   367, in compile_extra
>       return self._compile_bytecode()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   804, in _compile_bytecode
>       return self._compile_core()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   791, in _compile_core
>       res = pm.run(self.status)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   253, in run
>       raise patched_exception
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   245, in run
>       stage()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   438, in stage_objectmode_frontend
>       cres = self.frontend_looplift()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   428, in frontend_looplift
>       lifted=tuple(loops), lifted_from=None)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   887, in compile_ir
>       lifted_from=lifted_from)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   375, in compile_ir
>       return self._compile_ir()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   811, in _compile_ir
>       return self._compile_core()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   791, in _compile_core
>       res = pm.run(self.status)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   253, in run
>       raise patched_exception
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   245, in run
>       stage()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   652, in stage_objectmode_backend
>       self._backend(lowerfn, objectmode=True)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   628, in _backend
>       lowered = lowerfn()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   601, in backend_object_mode
>       self.flags)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line
>   1018, in py_lowering_stage
>       lower.lower()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line
>   173, in lower
>       self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line
>   214, in lower_normal_function
>       entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line
>   239, in lower_function_body
>       self.lower_block(block)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line
>   254, in lower_block
>       self.lower_inst(inst)
>
> File "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in
>   **exit**
>       self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
>
> File "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\errors.py",
>   line 585, in new_error_context
>       six.reraise(type(newerr), newerr, tb)
>
> File "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\six.py",
>   line 659, in reraise
>       raise value
>
> LoweringError: iters
>
> File "mandelbrot.py", line 17: def
>   mandelbrot(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,width,height,maxiter):
>       
>       for ix,re in enumerate(x):
>           points.append([])
>           ^

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It seems I need to initialize the variable 'iters' to 0 at the start of the loop. So this works when I put @jit before it. Anybody know why?

```
def mandelbrot(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,width,height,maxiter):
points=[]
x=np.linspace(xmin,xmax,width)
y=np.linspace(ymin,ymax,height)
for ix,re in enumerate(x):
    points.append([])
    for iy,im in enumerate(y):
        iters=0
        cx=re
        cy=im
        zx=0
        zy=0
        for n in range(maxiter):
            if zx*zx+zy*zy>4.0:
                iters=n
                break
            else:
                oldzx=zx
                oldzy=zy
                zy = 2*oldzx*oldzy+cy
                zx = oldzx*oldzx-oldzy*oldzy+cx  
                iters=n
        points[ix].append(iters)
return points
```